# Grep multiple occurrences given two strings and two integers

Tags: bash, grep

im looking for a bash script to count the occurences of a word in a given directory and it's subdirectory's files with this pattern:

```
^str1{n}str2{m}$
```

for example:

```
str1= yo
str2= uf
n= 3
m= 4
```

the match would be "yoyoyoufufufuf"

but i'm having trouble with grep

that's what i have tried

```
for file in $(find $dir)
do
    if [ -f $file ]; then
     echo "<$file>:<`grep '\<\$str1\{$n\}\$str2\{$m\}\>'' $file | wc -l >" >> a.txt
    fi 
done
```

should i use find?

Comment: Use the `-R` and `-c` options to `grep` to recurse without using `find` and count the matches without `wc`.

Answer (score 1):

@Barmar's comment is useful.

If I understand your question, I think this single `grep` command should do what you're looking for:

```
grep -r -c "^\($str1\)\{$n\}\($str2\)\{$m\}$" "$dir"
```

Note the combination of `-r` and `-c` causes `grep` to output zero-counts for non-matching files.  You can pipe to `grep -v ":0$"` to suppress this output if you require:

```
$ dir=.
$ str1=yo
$ str2=uf
$ n=3
$ m=4
$ cat youf 
yoyoyoufufufuf
$ grep -r -c "^\($str1\)\{$n\}\($str2\)\{$m\}$" "$dir"
./noyouf:0
./youf:1
./dir/youf:1
$ grep -r -c "^\($str1\)\{$n\}\($str2\)\{$m\}$" "$dir" | grep -v ":0$"
./youf:1
./dir/youf:1
$
```

Note also `$str1` and `$str2` need to be put in parentheses so that the `{m}` and `{n}` apply to everything within the parentheses and not just the last character.

Note the escaping of the `()` and `{}` as we require double-quotes `"`, so that the variables are expanded into the grep regular expression.